# Insert custom live template

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

Opened Resharper Templates Explorer, clicked on New Template button, created a new template which is now displayed in the list labeled "Templates in C# scope".

When I go back to Visual Studio and type in the template shortcut I assigned to the template, the shortcut is not recognized, when I press Ctrl+E,L or click on Resharper>Edit>Insert Live Template it is not in the list.

In Resharper>Options>Postfix Templates the list contains a subset of all the templates available in Template Explorer and I don't see anything else related to templates or a way to add my template to this list.

How do I insert my new template by typing the shortcut I assigned to it and how do I get it to show on the list of available templates when I press Ctrl+E,L?

Answer (score 0):

In Resharper Templates Explorer I clicked on Manage Layers button, clicked on Add Layer button under "This computer" entry, created a new dotsettings file in a folder I created for code snippets somewhere in my cloud folders, added new live template to that layer and now my live template is available with the shortcut and appears in the list when I press Ctrl+E,L...